# Find a specific pattern (regular expression) in each item of list of strings (Python)

Tags: python, list, expression

From this list `problems= ["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]`

I want to get these numbers `"\d*\s"` that means 32,3801,45,123

Is there a way to look in each item of list and search there with a list comprehension ?

I have only this attempt `print([x for x in problems if re.search(r'\d*\s',x)])`, but it prints whole item if the `"\d*\s"` is there, so I get again `["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]`

(My aim is have a lenght of the longer number of each item, that would be 3,4,2,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the first part before space in your strings. This can be done using group capturing. Here is the code you can use:

```
[re.search('(\d+)\s', x).group(1) for x in problems if re.search(r'(\d)*\s',x)]
```

Here `(\d+)\s` matches for one or more digits before a whitespace character and we extract the first group using the `group(1)` method.